# Integration of the product of probability densities

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Does a probability density $f(x|\alpha)$ multiplied by another probability density $g(\alpha)$ , where of course both integrate to one, also integrate to one if we integrate with respect to $\alpha$?

So do we have $\int^\infty_{-\infty} g(\alpha)f(x|\alpha)d\alpha =1$?

Comment: The integrand is the joint distribution:$f(x, \alpha)=f(x| \alpha)g(\alpha)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called Law of total probability. If you integrate wrt $\alpha$, you get the marginal of $X$:
$$
f(x)=\int_{A}f(x|\alpha)g(\alpha)d \alpha
$$

Comment: but that means it integrates to one right? @ZanCoul said no...

Comment: No, it doesn't integrate to 1. By integrating the joint distribution over one of the variables, you get the marginal of the other distribution. To get $1$ you need to integrate over $x$, i.e. take a double integral.

Answer (score 1):

It does not integrate to 1. It goes to $f(x)$. I would suggest you look at the discrete case to give yourself an insight.

If you are also looking at $\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(\alpha)f(x|\alpha)\, d\alpha$ and are wondering if the above gives you 1, take an example where $x$ and $\alpha$ are independent.